# I can't draw but I am super creative

Tags: freestyle

Here's a beginners question.

I have always been creative but I was never able to draw or put something on paper. However I can perfectly imagine my idea in 3D.

Now I have found Blender and I hope I can finally do something about my ideas.

So here's my question. Can I use blender to create new art, animations,... without being able how to draw?

Thank you!

Comment: You don't need to know how to draw to 3D model, but some of the principles of drawing certainly help with both practices. If you have certain projects you have in mind, I can link you some resources to get started learning the basics.

Answer (score 4):

I will answer this, but avoid questions that are opinion based like this on this stack exchange. Take the [Tour](https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour) here.

Of course you can! Drawing is not required at all for blender. You can utilize tools like sculpt and modeling which dont require knowing how to draw. I am absolutely horrible at drawing, and I know how to do these things using blender.

Comment: I second this - Straight drawing, I could probably screw up a stickman - blender has allowed me to express myself artistically in ways my hands and fingers could never even dream of. If you want a good tutorial series to get going, a great place to start is Andrew Price's (the Blender Guru) donut tutorial. Most people on this site are familiar with the series as well, so it makes it easier to find answers if/when you have questions. Link is here - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TPrnSACiTJ4