Can someone with no drawing/art skills make really good 3D models with Blender?
My son has a 3D printer that he and I enjoy very much. We just print things we find on the Internet, because neither of us know how to do any 3D modeling. I am trying to decide whether to learn 3D modeling because I have a lot of ideas for things I'd like to make and print.
Here's the thing: I can't draw worth a hill of beans. There's no way I could on paper draw a picture of what I would want to make a model of. I can see it in my head, but I can't translate it into a drawing, just like I can see Bugs Bunny in my head but can't draw him worth crap.
I'm asking this of everyone, but especially anyone on here with no drawing talent: Is it possible to become a good 3D modeler with Blender (or anything else) if you can't draw on paper? Do the tools you learn to use in Blender help you overcome your deficiencies with a pencil? I know you can instantly create circles and other shapes and put them together and make all sorts of adjustments. Is the skill involved with that different than the skill of drawing? Could a person that cannot draw a 3D view of a car on paper succeed in making a 3D model of a car on Blender (once they've learned all about how to use the software)?
I sure hope I'm conveying this right. I don't want to waste my time learning any sort of 3D modeling software if I'm just doomed from the start due to my poor artistic skills.
Thanks!

Yes you can be a bad illustrator but a good 3D modeler, but you can also be bad at both   ;)   you need to test and you'll quickly see

The site it for questions about Blender software, opinion based posts like this one is considered off topic. Try blender on reddit or blenderartists site to get a proper discussion with the community

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/126822/should-i-just-quit-blender-when-after-two-weeks-of-learning-and-watching-tutoria/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/215856/i-cant-draw-but-i-am-super-creative

I could literally mess up a stickman. I fell in love with blender because I was finally able to express myself and my ideas with no regard to my total lack of drawing talent. It felt like the artist inside finally had a way to express himself. So, TLDR is that would be a big YES from me - Not only can you be a 3D artist with no drawing ability, in my opinion, it can even compensate for a lack of drawing ability with regards to artistic expression. - It's like a picture that you can tweak over and over to your liking, and even use some cheats (modifiers) to do some of the hard work for you.
